# Given a square Matrix A such that $A^2 = I$ then nullity(I$-A) + nullity(I$+A) = n

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been trying to finish answer this problem for some hours.
The questions are:

Given a square Matrix A such that $A^2 = I$ then nullity (I$-A) + nullity(I$+A) = n;
Hint: express $A^2 = I$ in terms of (I$-A) and (I$+A) and use the dimension theorem.

Comment: @Tom Actually, $A$ is a reflection map. You can obtain the corresponding projection map like so: $(A + I)/2$.

Comment: Yeah! I misread the question. I read it as, $A^2=A$ which is not the case.